# How can I use the SQLServerDriver in IntelliJ when I run/debug a file's main()?

Tags: java, sql-server, intellij-idea, jdbc

I am able to use the SQLServerDriver when I run my project through maven and can successfully read/write to my db. I'm testing some changes in a specific file and I'm trying to test that individual file by right-clicking the file and running the file.

When it gets to run the setup code it throws an exception (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver).

The code:

```
        Connection conn = null;
        Class.forName(dbDriverMsSQL);
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbConnectionString);
```

with this separately defined: 
`public static String dbDriverMsSQL = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";`

I'm using the following dependency in my pom.xml:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>7.4.1.jre8</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Is there some additional setting that I have to configure to be able to read/write from my main()?

Comment: Your dependency scope is test - do you use this code in a Test? If not this might cause the error. You can also try Class.forName(SQLServerDriver.class); If IntelliJ can't find the import you have a problem with your depenencies.

Comment: didnt even consider that! I removed the scope and that was it. its working! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting @TomStroemer 's comment to mark this resolved:

> Your dependency scope is test - do you use this code in a Test? If not this might cause the error. You can also try Class.forName(SQLServerDriver.class); If IntelliJ can't find the import you have a problem with your depenencies.
>   I removed the scope and I could run successfully.